# How create a battery level array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, achartengine, batterylevel

I need to create a battery level array to insert it in a graph like

```
values.add( batterylevel )
```

How can i create this array? I mean, i know how create an array but i don't know how create one for the battery level. How can i do it? This is a way to have the battery level

```
public float getBatteryLevel() {
    Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

    // Error checking that probably isn't needed but I added just in case.
    if(level == -1 || scale == -1) {
        return 50.0f;
    }

    return ((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f; 
}
```

I need have `double` value to intert it in the chart.

Comment: don't you need to store the return values from your function over a period of time so that you can plot a graph. if not you will only have a single point isnt it?

Comment: Well of course i need to display more points. Because i want show the battery usage during a day for example or more. But i need to create an array of battery level but i don't know how do it..

Comment: Well where are you storing the battery level?

Comment: I think i need a sqlLite database that for now i haven't already created. And there i'll store the battery level..i think. But it's here the problem.. How can i store this type of value.. And then how can i create the array? In mt code `level` returns the battery level that could be for example (60,65,70,75).. But this `level` have i to transform it in an array? I can't understand what i have to do at this point.

Comment: Save the return value from getBatteryLevel() in a SQLite database along with a timestamp. When you want to retrieve the values you order by timestamp ascending and then you iterate the list, getting your values in order. After that you take all the values and put in a graph. How and where you put in a graph is another story.

Comment: wait..so, if i have understand, what i have to do is: make a service with a AlarmManager that every 30 minutes register the battery level. Every time that this service register the value it been saved in the database and then the values will write in the graph?